# Simplifying $ \frac{2x-x\lvert x-1\rvert+x\lvert x\rvert+5}{\lvert x\rvert+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

How would one begin to simplify the following?

$$ \frac{2x-x\lvert x-1\rvert+x\lvert x\rvert+5}{\lvert x\rvert+1}$$

I have found the domain as

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x+5}{1-x},  & \ {(-\infty,0]} \\[4pt]
\dfrac{2x^2+x+5}{x+1}, & \ {[0,1)} \\[4pt]
\dfrac{5x+5}{x+1}, & \ {[1,+\infty)} \\
\end{cases}$$

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you "found the domain"? If that was your work, I'm guessing that you're on the right track.

Comment: You’ve done the hard part. That’s not the domain. That’s the function. But You could simplify the 3 expressions somewhat. e.g. $ \frac{5x+5}{x+1}=5$ on $[1, \infty)$ because $-1 \notin [1, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints

When dealing with something like |r|, you want to consider two cases:
$r < 0$ and $r \geq 0.$

Here you have 3 conditions to worry about.

1. Is $(x - 1) \geq 0$ or is $(x - 1) < 0.$
2. Is $(x) \geq 0$ or is $(x) < 0.$
3. Is $|x| + 1 = 0.$  If possible, this would make the denominator $= 0,$ which
   is not allowed.  However, this situation is impossible because $|x|$ can not equal
   $-1$.

Try to "*collapse*" the cases that represent points 1 and 2 above into 3 distinct
intervals.  Then, for each interval, create a totally distinct function that
applies only to that interval.

---

I overlooked that the OP has shown work and that therefore, it is okay to complete the problem.

The original function is

$$ f(x) = \frac{2x-x\lvert x-1\rvert+x\lvert x\rvert+5}{\lvert x\rvert+1}$$

The three intervals will be

Interval 1: $x < 0.~$ The specific function will be $f_1(x).$

$$ f_1(x) = \frac{2x ~- ~[(x)(1 - x)] ~+~ [x(-x)] ~+~ 5}{(-x) ~+ ~1}.$$

Interval 2: $0 \leq x < 1.~$ The specific function will be $f_2(x).$

$$ f_2(x) = \frac{2x ~- ~[(x)(1 - x)] ~+~ [x(x)] ~+~ 5}{(x) ~+ ~1}.$$

Interval 3: $1 \leq x.~$ The specific function will be $f_3(x).$

$$ f_3(x) = \frac{2x ~- ~[(x)(x - 1)] ~+~ [x(x)] ~+~ 5}{(x) ~+ ~1}.$$

At this point, none of $~f_1(x), f_2(x),~$ or $~f_3(x)$ are employing any absolute value signs.  Now, you can consider whether there is any simplification that is common to all three functions $~f_1(x), f_2(x),~$ and $~f_3(x).$

From my perspective, other than multiplying the numerators out, I see no other possible simplification that can be applied to all three functions.